# How to dill a class and modify it later?

Tags: python, serialization, dill

I am currently using the dill library for Python and I am using it to dill a class.  This is the class

```
class QQQ:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.total = 0

    def add_1(self, add):
        self.total = 1 + add
        # To test the below after loading the saved dill
        # self.total = 101 + add

    @property
    def get_total(self):
        return self.total
```

Then I instantiate my class and dill it

```
import dill

path = '/path/file'
dill.settings['recurse'] = True
from x.qqq import QQQ

qqq = QQQ(name='Test1')
qqq.add_1(100)
with open(path, 'wb') as f:
    dill.dump(qqq, f)
```

```
class QQQ:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.total = 0

    def add_1(self, add):
        # self.total = 1 + add
        self.total = 101 + add

    @property
    def get_total(self):
        return self.total
```

Although, if I modify this QQQ class after dilling it then I load my dumped file:

```
import dill
path = '/path/file'
dill.settings['recurse'] = True

with open(path, 'rb') as f:
    old_class = dill.load(f)

old_class.add_1(100)
total = old_class.get_total
```

It uses the **modified** class and not the class I dilled earlier.

Comment: Where are you modifying the `QQQ` class? I don't see any code that's changing the class.

Comment: @martineau I just added the modification. My main question is why doesnt it refer to the dilled object but the actual class that was modified

Comment: All you did was add the definition of your `QQQ` class. Your code is **not** modifying the class anywhere — so your question doesn't really make any sense as it stands. Perhaps you are confusing a class and an instance of the class, I cannot tell…

Comment: The method **add_1** was modified: **self.total = 101 + add** whereas in the previous it was: **self.total = 1 + add**

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Anyway, redefining the class just assigns a new value — a class object — to `QQQ`. That isn't going to automagically change the existing _instance_ of the previous version of the class (`old_class`). Unlike `pickle`, the `dill` module puts class definitions in the files it creates. If you want a class with changeable methods, you should probably implement it another way…

Comment: Mike answered my question below. Sorry for not being clear enough in my post, will try to make it clearer next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the `dill` author. It ignores the stored class, because that was determined to be the proper thing to do.  If you have redefined the class, then you have two choices, use the newly defined class... or ignore it and use the old class definition.  Older versions of `dill` ignored the new class definition, but then that was deemed to not be the correct default behavior. Recent versions all will defer to any redefined class, by default.

If you do want to ignore the new class definition, then you have to do it at load time, as noted below.

```
>>> import dill
>>> class QQQ(object):
...     def __init__(self):    
...         self.total = 0
...     def increment(self, n=1):
...         self.total += n
... 
>>> q = QQQ() 
>>> q.increment()
>>> q.total
1
>>> dill.dump(q, open('qqq.pkl', 'wb'))
>>>
```

And then restart your session.  You get the new class definition, unless you use the `ignore` flag.

```
>>> import dill
>>> class QQQ(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.total = 0
...     def increment(self, n=10):
...         self.total += n
...     def decrement(self, n=10):
...         self.total -= n
... 
>>> q = dill.load(open('qqq.pkl', 'rb'))
>>> q.total
1
>>> q.increment()
>>> q.total
11
>>> p = dill.load(open('qqq.pkl', 'rb'), ignore=True)
>>> p.total
1
>>> p.increment()
>>> p.total
2
```

Comment: This is my problem. I have been able to try the ignore=True argument but still facing the problem. I believe my problem is linked to the following: https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/issues/330

Comment: @john279: I was hoping Mike would respond to your question is some fashsion — since he can speak authoritatively about what the `dill` module does.

Comment: @john279: if your file is a local module (i.e. not installed as a package), right now I believe that doesn't work.  There is a PR with changes that do address it, but there's issues with that code.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns can you let me know which PR you are referring to? It might be useful. Thanks

Comment: There's a number of PRs/Issues... but I think the code to enable it is here, just not "active". https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/blob/master/dill/__diff.py  -- I'd have to track down the issue this originates from...